# Не работает вход на stackoverflow c авторизацией ВКонтакте

Tags: stackoverflow

Давно не заходил на stackoverflow.

Сейчас при попытке войти и выборе "Войти через ВКонтакте", как я делал это раньше, пишет

error

Comment: Вам сюда: [Stack Overflow Meta](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com)

Comment: Там чтобы задать вопрос, надо авторизоваться. А авторизация не работает.

Comment: @Пушистик более того...вот сюда https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/12116/191482  ...........но всем пофиг

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса, потому что дубликат меты https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/12116/191482

Comment: Зарегистрируйтесь заново без авторизации через ВК, потом через форму поддержки попросите объединить учетные записи. И после этого не используйте авторизацию через ВК.

Comment: Спасибо! Если с авторизацией через VK все так грустно, попробую пройти по пути восстановления доступа...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как было указано в комментариях, этот вопрос является дублем для вопроса

[При авторизации через VK черный экран с надписью erorr](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/12116/191482)